# what's the principle of particle samples' clusters in the amcl packages?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

-

```
 when  I looked at the amcl package,i found amcl uses K-D Tree data structure to store the whole particle samples  as its leaf nodes. And also i found a particle samples set corresponds to some clusters,what's the principle of clustering  the K-D Tree
```

(https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/amcl/src/amcl/pf/pf.c#L475)?  what's the  knowledge  in  this function?

-

```
Thanks  very much , any advice would be appreciated!!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242210/what%27s-the-principle-of-particle-samples%27-clusters-in-the-amcl--packages?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's look into pf_sample_set_t type.

```
typedef struct _pf_sample_set_t {
  // The samples
  int sample_count;
  pf_sample_t *samples;

  // A kdtree encoding the histogram
  pf_kdtree_t *kdtree;

  // Clusters
  int cluster_count, cluster_max_count;
  pf_cluster_t *clusters;

  // Filter statistics
  pf_vector_t mean;
  pf_matrix_t cov;
  int converged; 
} pf_sample_set_t;
```

Sample particles are stored as an array hold by the pointer, `samples`, instead of `kdtree`.
The kdtree is for constructing weight histogram of particles.
The purposes of this histogram are to provide the number of non-empty bins for KLD-sampling and to calculate mean and covariance values from each cluster. This clustering algorithm for the kdtree histogram seems like a type of density-based clustering algorithms. Nodes connected to each other are labeled as a same cluster where connectivity is determined based on neighbor nodes. In pf_kdtree.c of amcl package, the neighbor node, `nnode`, of a node is

```
nkey[0] = node->key[0] + (i / 9) - 1;
nkey[1] = node->key[1] + ((i % 9) / 3) - 1;
nkey[2] = node->key[2] + ((i % 9) % 3) - 1;
nnode = pf_kdtree_find_node(self, self->root, nkey);
```

where `key` is the spatial information of a node.

---

Originally posted by [chung](https://answers.ros.org/users/32005/chung/) with karma: 81 on 2017-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2017-11-30**:
@chung,thanks a lot !!!